# VMware: Push Changes from Base VM to a derived Snapshot

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I have a base VM just with the operating system on it. There are snapshots of this VM with different installed applications. Now I'd like to provide several software updates to these snapshots. But I don't want to install them on each snapshot but only on the base machine once.

**Is it possible to merge virtual machines from bottom up? (base VM to Snapshot)**

It doesn't matter for me, of what kind the resulting VM will be. Full or linked clones would both be ok.

Comment: When you say *"derived"*, how did you clone the systems?

Comment: I'm talking about simple snapshots. But every other cloning mechanism would be an option for me, too (if it served my need: merging).

Comment: This still isn't clear.

Comment: It doesn't matter for the question, what kind of cloning mechanism I use. Is it more understandable now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. From the VMware docs:

> "All files available on the parent at the moment of the snapshot
>   continue to remain available to the linked clone. Ongoing changes to
>   the virtual disk of the parent do not affect the linked clone, and
>   changes to the disk of the linked clone do not affect the parent." [[VMware Fusion 6 Docs](http://pubs.vmware.com/fusion-6/topic/com.vmware.fusion.help.doc/GUID-96D07E71-FF5D-4E82-A5BD-0B15586432E4.html)]

Answer (score 1):

Nope. This won't be possible with standard vSphere and the normal snapshot/clone operations.